# Selecting Cell Value from Filtered Table

Tags: excel, select, autofilter, vba

I have a macro that goes through a Table and picks out the value I want value want ("ref") from Col 5 which is then used in rest of code.

```
Dim Lobj As ListObject

Set Lobj = SourceBk.Sheets("RefSheet2_x").ListObjects("Table1")

For x = 1 To Lobj.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

   Ref = Lobj.DataBodyRange(x, 5)

Next x
```

What I need is to be able to run the code so it works on just the visible rows when the Table is filtered (normally filter will be in on Col 2 but may include filters on other cols). My current code ignores any filtering I have applied and works on the whole Table.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check the entire row's `Hidden` property. Something along those lines:

```
Public Sub Answer()
    Dim Lobj As ListObject
    Dim Ref As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Set Lobj = SourceBk.Sheets("RefSheet2_x").ListObjects("Table1")

    With Lobj
        For x = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            If Not .DataBodyRange.Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden Then
                Ref = .DataBodyRange(x, 5).Value
                '...
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - its coming up with "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the If Not .rows line.

Comment: Perfecto. Thank you :)